LogLog plot with errors in matplotlib
I want to get plot in LogLog scale with errors. What i should to fix here? As far as I understand, the ability to add errors is not built into loglog method.
x = np.arange(182).astype('float64')
y = np.arange(182).astype('float64')
yerr = np.arange(182).astype('float64')
with open("/home/erg/ch5", "r") as myfiley:
    datay = myfiley.read().splitlines()
with open("/home/erg/ch6", "r") as myfilex:
     datax = myfilex.read().splitlines()
 with open("/home/erg/ch4", "r") as myfilez:
     dataz = myfilez.read().splitlines()
for i in range(len(datax)):
    x[i] = datax[i]
    y[i] = datay[i]
    yerr[i] = dataz[i]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=35)
ax.set_title('4RIGHT-ACCIDENT', fontsize=40)
plt.xlabel('AMP', fontsize=35, color='black')
plt.ylabel('COUNTS', fontsize=35, color='black')
ax.loglog(x, y, yerr=yerr, linewidth=5)
plt.show()


Please provide a minimal example, and what is wrong with your code as it is.

File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Astley.py", line 37, in 
ax.loglog(x, y, yerr=yerr, linewidth=5)
File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1673, in loglog
l = self.plot(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/init.py", line 1870, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1528, in plot
for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):

File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 406, in _grab_next_args
for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 396, in _plot_args
seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)

File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 300, in _makeline
seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 421, in init
self.update(kwargs)

File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 888, in update
for k, v in props.items()]
File "/home/erg/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 881, in _update_property
raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
AttributeError: Unknown property yerr

Please edit your question and see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please edit the post and add the missing error trace. Please also add some test data to create reproducible example code.

I adjusted your code a bit, so it does not read you local files but it plots the simulated data (np.arange):
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(182)
y = np.arange(182)
yerr = np.arange(182).astype("float64") * 0.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=35)
ax.set_title('4RIGHT-ACCIDENT', fontsize=40)
plt.xlabel('AMP', fontsize=35, color='black')
plt.ylabel('COUNTS', fontsize=35, color='black')
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr)
# set the x and y scale manually:
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()

Which is the same plot (but with error bars) compared to:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=35)
ax.set_title('4RIGHT-ACCIDENT', fontsize=40)
plt.xlabel('AMP', fontsize=35, color='black')
plt.ylabel('COUNTS', fontsize=35, color='black')
ax.loglog(x, y)


